# Access Symbol(_latestValue) of an Observable Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, observable

I want to get the value from a observable array myViewModel[index]["Symbol(_latestValue)"]

With "...myViewModel[index]..." I've access of the object. (picture)

[image]

I need the value from "Symbol(_latestValue)".

Is there any way to access it ?

To receive the value with "...myViewModel[index]()..." has no effect. result->undefined

Comment: Calling the observable without arguments should return the `_latestValue`. The symbol property is for the internals of the library to track state. Can you share some more code so we can figure out why `()` would return `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't access field with `Symbol(key)` key. That because `Symbol` will create unique key each time it called, so unless you obtained that key, you cannot generate it by yourself.
For ex. `Symbol('key') !== Symbol('key')`
More on that is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. No solution unfortunately.